# Minor Nitpick - Please consider removing redundant svg-icon on teams

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-for-teams

Can we consider removing the many instances of the "lock" icon across the teams system?

It makes the page look a bit busy. I can understand that you guys are trying to ensure people know this is a private area, but I think it would be sufficient to have it only on the button to post a question. I think there is too much of this lock icon across the page, and when I viewed the source and did a `display: none;` on it it looked so much better considering most teams use their company logo.

[image]

Compare this with the removal of these:

[image]

The page looks a helluva lot cleaner now just by removing these. I know it is minor, but I think having too many of these just clutters the page, and I always find myself looking at this icon over and over. I think the lock being simply on the button is enough to tell us "hey this is private..." all the other icons are noise. **By taking the icons off the page I feel the page lost 5 lbs already!**

Comment: Minor Nitpick - Please consider free hand arrows on your screen shot.

Comment: Minor Nitpick #2 - Please consider a red freehand circular shape to highlight these svg's. They are very small

Comment: That second screenshot is tiny; can you take a new one that is at least 100% zoom level?

Comment: @jpmc26 I fixed it. It was just a wrong number.

Comment: Better replacement for (lock icon)+"Ask a question" -- change the title to "Ask your team a question"

Comment: that does look pretty nifty with display none. though, I too prefer free-hand red circles. :) I'll pass the feedback on to the design team.